# Why does my rock paper scissors program not work properly?

Tags: javascript

I've recently started learning code and I'm trying to build a rock paper scissor game using vanilla javascript. It prompts the user 5 times for a hand and then declares if the player or computer won based on randomly generated the computer hand. I was doing okay with the following code:

```js
let computerPlay = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  if (randomNumber === 0) {
    return ("rock");
  } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return ("paper");
  } else {
    return ("scisscor");
  }
}

let playerPlay = () => {
  let userInput = prompt("Choose rock, paper or scisscor:");
  while (userInput === null) {
    userInput = prompt("Come on, choose one of rock, paper or scisscor:");
  }
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  return userInput;
}

let playerScore = 0;
let compScore = 0;
let tie = 0;

let win = () => {
  playerScore++;
  console.log("You won!");
  console.log(`Your score is ${playerScore}, computer score is ${compScore} and there is ${tie} ties`);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------------------")
}

let lose = () => {
  compScore++;
  console.log("You lost!");
  console.log(`Your score is ${playerScore}, computer score is ${compScore} and there is ${tie} ties`);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------------------")
}

let draw = () => {
  tie++;
  console.log("It's a draw");
  console.log(`Your score is ${playerScore}, computer score is ${compScore} and there is ${tie} ties`);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------------------")
}


let gameWinner = () => {
  if (playerScore > compScore) {
    console.log(`You won the game! Your score was ${playerScore} and computer score was ${compScore}`);
  } else if (compScore > playerScore) {
    console.log(`You lost the game! Your score was ${playerScore} and computer score was ${compScore}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`It was a tie since both you and computer had the same score of ${playerScore}`);
  }
}

let playRound = () => {
  const playerSelection = playerPlay();
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  switch (playerSelection + computerSelection) {
    case "rockscisscor":
    case "paperrock":
    case "scissorpaper":
      win();
      break;
    case "rockpaper":
    case "scissorrock":
    case "paperscissor":
      lose();
      break;
    case "rockrock":
    case "scissorscissor":
    case "paperpaper":
      draw();
      break;
  }
}

let game = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    playRound();
  }
  gameWinner();
}

game();
```

When I went to the console it displayed the following:

```
index.html:57 It's a draw
index.html:58 Your score is 0, computer score is 0 and there is 1 ties
index.html:59 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:57 It's a draw
index.html:58 Your score is 0, computer score is 0 and there is 2 ties
index.html:59 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:50 You lost!
index.html:51 Your score is 0, computer score is 1 and there is 2 ties
index.html:52 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:57 It's a draw
index.html:58 Your score is 0, computer score is 1 and there is 3 ties
index.html:59 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:43 You won!
index.html:44 Your score is 1, computer score is 1 and there is 3 ties
index.html:45 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:69 It was a tie since both you and computer had the same score of 1
```

Now the problem arises after I wanted to show the hands of each round. So I made a new function called roundResults that would display on the console what the player input and what the computer-generated.

```js
let computerPlay = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  if (randomNumber === 0) {
    return ("rock");
  } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return ("paper");
  } else {
    return ("scisscor");
  }
}

let playerPlay = () => {
  let userInput = prompt("Choose rock, paper or scisscor:");
  while (userInput === null) {
    userInput = prompt("Come on, choose one of rock, paper or scisscor:");
  }
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  return userInput;
}

let roundResults = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
  console.log("You selected:", playerPlay());
  console.log("Computer selected:", computerPlay());

}


let playerScore = 0;
let compScore = 0;
let tie = 0;

let win = () => {
  playerScore++;
  console.log("You won!");
  console.log(`Your score is ${playerScore}, computer score is ${compScore} and there is ${tie} ties`);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------------------")
}

let lose = () => {
  compScore++;
  console.log("You lost!");
  console.log(`Your score is ${playerScore}, computer score is ${compScore} and there is ${tie} ties`);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------------------")
}

let draw = () => {
  tie++;
  console.log("It's a draw");
  console.log(`Your score is ${playerScore}, computer score is ${compScore} and there is ${tie} ties`);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------------------")
}


let gameWinner = () => {
  if (playerScore > compScore) {
    console.log(`You won the game! Your score was ${playerScore} and computer score was ${compScore}`);
  } else if (compScore > playerScore) {
    console.log(`You lost the game! Your score was ${playerScore} and computer score was ${compScore}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`It was a tie since both you and computer had the same score of ${playerScore}`);
  }
}

let playRound = () => {
  const playerSelection = playerPlay();
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  switch (playerSelection + computerSelection) {
    case "rockscisscor":
    case "paperrock":
    case "scissorpaper":
      win();
      roundResults(playerPlay, computerPlay);
      break;
    case "rockpaper":
    case "scissorrock":
    case "paperscissor":
      lose();
      roundResults(playerPlay, computerPlay);
      break;
    case "rockrock":
    case "scissorscissor":
    case "paperpaper":
      draw();
      roundResults(playerPlay, computerPlay);
      break;
  }
}

let game = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    playRound();
  }
  gameWinner();
}

game();
```

This entirely messed up my code and now it says I drawed when I should have lost, or says I lost when I should draw. It also gives me more than 5 prompts to enter a hand when it should only ask me 5 times.

```
index.html:49 You won!
index.html:50 Your score is 1, computer score is 0 and there is 0 ties
index.html:51 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:37 You selected: rock
index.html:38 Computer selected: rock
index.html:56 You lost!
index.html:57 Your score is 1, computer score is 1 and there is 0 ties
index.html:58 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:37 You selected: rock
index.html:38 Computer selected: rock
index.html:63 It's a draw
index.html:64 Your score is 1, computer score is 1 and there is 1 ties
index.html:65 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:37 You selected: rock
index.html:38 Computer selected: paper
index.html:49 You won!
index.html:50 Your score is 2, computer score is 1 and there is 1 ties
index.html:51 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:37 You selected: rock
index.html:38 Computer selected: paper
index.html:63 It's a draw
index.html:64 Your score is 2, computer score is 1 and there is 2 ties
index.html:65 ------------------------------------------------------------
index.html:37 You selected: rock
index.html:38 Computer selected: paper
index.html:71 You won the game! Your score was 2 and computer score was 1
```

Why it was working before, but now that I put one function in it that should only display the hands of each round is messing up my logic for the rest of the script.

Comment: Params `playerChoice`, `computerChoice` of function `roundResult()` aren't even used. Instead it just runs `playerPlay()` and `computerPlay()`? When you add extra features to code you don't backup a working copy first?

Comment: Your code isn't fubared from adding `roundResults()` it's the function `game()` that's responsible for repeating 5 times because it consists of a `for` loop with a count of 5.